# Initiate an async operation with a result

Tags: c++, boost-asio, c++20, c++-coroutine

I'm currently working on a project that uses boost asio for networking. I want to implement a function that look like this:

```
template<command T, response R = typename T::response_type>
auto send_command(T c) -> boost::asio::awaitable<R> {
    // ...
}
```

In my code, when I'm writing the command to the socket, I will eventually receive a response with the result. I may receive any number of other responses in the socket before getting the response to a specific command.

I figured I could use `async_initiate` to make sending a command an asynchronous operation composed of a write and a read.

I've already used `async_initiate` to start asynchronous operations, but it was of the type `boost::asio::awaitable<void>`. And the code looked like this:

```
// returns the awaitable for the coroutine to suspend
return asio::async_initiate<CompletionToken, void(void)>(
    [self = shared_from_this()](auto&& handler) {
        self->callback_queue.push(std::forward<decltype(handler)>(handler));
    }
);

// later

auto& resume = callback_queue.front();
resume(); // resume the suspended coroutine
```

But I can't figure where to put the return value here when It's not void!

```
auto const command_id = std::int32_t{...};

auto& resume_command = commands_continuations[command_id];
resume_command(response_result); // Send the `co_await` result in parameters??
```

I'm simply confused how to send the return of the awaitable and how to initiate the asynchronous operation with a result.

Comment: I know that the signature passed to `async_result` is what determines what return type your token-type's specialization ends up deducing to. 

I'm not intimate with `async_initiate` yet - I find the documentation is _very flimsy_ on that part yet (basically absent). So, I can't show it for use_awaitable, but perhaps it helps showing the analogous for other types of completion tokens: https://wandbox.org/permlink/ApEp5L3nu1F1eFXZ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that there are a number of fixed signature a async operation can take.

The `void(void)` is one, but to have a result, we can simply use `void(T)`:

```
return asio::async_initiate<CompletionToken, void(R)>(
    [self = shared_from_this()](auto&& handler) {
        self->callback_queue.push(std::forward<decltype(handler)>(handler));
    }
);
```

The `handler` will be a callable that takes a `R` as parameter and will become the result of the `co_await` operation.

To have exception handling, cancellation, I tried two different ways to propagate exceptions. One is to send an `std::exception_ptr` and the other was to use `boost::system::error_code`. In my case, I choose error code as I'm more comfortable using them.

```
return asio::async_initiate<CompletionToken, void(boost::system::error_code, R)>(
    [self = shared_from_this()](auto&& handler) {
        self->callback_queue.push(std::forward<decltype(handler)>(handler));
    }
);
```

The callback take form of a move only function that matches the signature `void(boost::system::error_code, R)`. I call it like this:

```
auto callback = std::exchange(callback_queue[command_id], {});
if (result) {
    // resumes the coroutine normally with the result
    callback(boost::system::error_code{}, *result);
} else {
    // Throws exception in the coroutine
    callback(make_error_code(boost::system::errc::operation_canceled), R{});
}
```

There is more information about it in the documentation about [ASIO/Networking TS](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/outcome/doc/html/recipes/asio-integration-1-70.html)